# Cardinality of maximal subsets with some property

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. Is it true that all maximal (with respect to "$\subset$") subsets $D\subset X$ with the following property:

$$
\|x-y\| \geq1 \textrm{ for } x\neq y, x,y\in D,
$$
are of the same cardinality?

Comment: @Yigoros: Why did you tag it as set theory, twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

For every normed space $X$ we can define as $\alpha$, the cardinality of the set of minimum cardinality which is dense in $X$.

Clearly, $\alpha\ge\aleph_0$.

For every such set $D$, described in the question, we shall show that $\lvert D\rvert=\alpha$.

1. It is not hard to see that the set $E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} 2^{-n}D$ is dense in $X$, and the cardinality of $E$ is the same as the cardinality of $E$. Thus $$\,\lvert D\rvert=\lvert E\rvert\ge\alpha.$$
2. If $F$ is dense in $X$ and $\lvert F\rvert=\alpha$, then every ball centered at an element of $D$ with radius $1/3$ contains an element of $F$. Different balls, different elements. Thus
   $$\,\lvert D\rvert\le\alpha.$$